# How to run multiple animations at the same time in LibGDX

Tags: animation, libgdx, blender

I have created a Blender model that uses an armature with bone constraints to animate the model. After exporting the model as a `.fbx` file and passing it through fbx-conv, my animation is split up into several animations.

Each animation ends up with an ID similar to `"MyObject|MyAnimation"`.

In other words, I need to run all of these sub-animations at once to run my full animation.

I tried several [AnimationController](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/AnimationController.html) methods. First I tried calling `AnimationController.setAnimation()` for each of the animations, which doesn't work because it cancels the current animation each time it is called.

The `AnimationController.animate()` method sounds like it is supposed to do what I want, but I just get the same result as with `.setAnimation()`.

Here is the code I tried:

```
instance = new ModelInstance( myModel );
controller = new AnimationController( instance );

for( Animation animation : instance.animations ) {
    controller.animate( animation.id, 0 );
}
```

Is this not how `.animate()` is intended to work?

Also, I am not entirely certain of how to correctly use the second argument, `transitionTime`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: "If you want to apply multiple animations to the same ModelInstance, you can use multiple AnimationControllers, as long as they don't interfere with each other (don't affect the same nodes)." https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm not sure how I missed reading that in the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xoppa pointed out, the [LibGDX docs on 3D Animations and Skinning](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning) says the following:

> "If you want to apply multiple animations to the same ModelInstance, you can use multiple AnimationControllers, as long as they don't interfere with each other (don't affect the same nodes)."

---

**Example:**

```
ModelInstance myInstance = new ModelInstance( myModel );

AnimationController controllerOne = new AnimationController( myInstance );
AnimationController controllerTwo = new AnimationController( myInstance );

controllerOne.setAnimation( "FirstAnimationId", -1 );
controllerTwo.setAnimation( "SecondAnimationId", -1 );
```

Then in your render loop, you will also need to call `.update(delta)` on all of your `AnimationController`s:

```
controllerOne.update( Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() );
controllerTwo.update( Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() );
```